# Hermes JMS with TIBCO EMS in ssl Mode

Tags: tibco-ems, hermes-jms

I am trying to connect to tibco ems server from hermes jms.I have found many results to connect to tibco with tcp connection.

Can any body please share the steps involved to connect to SSL enabled connection.here are the configuration and error i am getting from current hermes JMS.
[image]
[image]

Doubt any further ssl parameters has to be passed

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass Keystore certificate only and check the certificate is valid.
It should not be expired one.

Comment: ,i tried adding the valide keystore file xxx.jks to the property ,still the same error